# Strategy pattern in Spring boot application for payment gateway and methods

Tags: spring-boot, design-patterns, dependency-injection, payment-gateway, strategy-pattern

I have a controller where I am being passed a gatewayid for different providers. I have a `BasePaymentService` interface which is implemented by Payu service and Razorpay service for now.
I want to avoid using `if` condition for and have the strategy added without changing code and have the container inject correct strategy.

1. How do I add a strategy pattern here?
2. Would callback method be also a part of strategy here?
3. How do I account for different payment methods here? (cards, wallets)

**BasePaymentService**

```
public interface BasePaymentService {
    PaymentDetail makePayment(PaymentDetail detail);
    Payment callbackPayment(PaymentCallback detail);
}
```

**Concrete PaymentService**

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class PayuPaymentService implements BasePaymentService {

    @Autowired
    PaymentRepository paymentRepository;

    public PaymentDetail makePayment(PaymentDetail paymentDetail) {
        PaymentUtil paymentUtil = new PaymentUtil();
        paymentDetail = paymentUtil.populatePaymentDetail(paymentDetail);
        savePaymentDetail(paymentDetail);
        return paymentDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public Payment callbackPayment(PaymentCallback paymentResponse) {
        log.info("inside callback service >>>>>");
        String msg = "Transaction failed.";
        Payment payment = paymentRepository.findByTxnId(paymentResponse.getTxnid());
        if(payment != null) {
            log.info("in condition callback service");
            //TODO validate the hash
            PaymentStatus paymentStatus = null;
            if(paymentResponse.getStatus().equals("failure")){
                paymentStatus = PaymentStatus.Failed;
            }else if(paymentResponse.getStatus().equals("success")) {
                paymentStatus = PaymentStatus.Success;
                msg = "Transaction success";
            }
            payment.setPaymentStatus(paymentStatus);
            payment.setMihpayId(paymentResponse.getMihpayid());
            payment.setMode(paymentResponse.getMode());
            paymentRepository.save(payment);
        }
        return payment;
    }

    private void savePaymentDetail(PaymentDetail paymentDetail) {
        log.info("in proceedPayment save");
        Payment payment = new Payment();
        payment.setAmount(Double.parseDouble(paymentDetail.getAmount()));
        payment.setEmail(paymentDetail.getEmail());
        payment.setName(paymentDetail.getName());
        payment.setPaymentDate(new Date());
        payment.setPaymentStatus(PaymentStatus.Pending);
        payment.setPhone(paymentDetail.getPhone());
        payment.setProductInfo(paymentDetail.getProductInfo());
        payment.setTxnId(paymentDetail.getTxnId());
        paymentRepository.save(payment);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Api(value = "swipe: payment Service", tags = "Example")
@Validated
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping(value = CommonConstants.BASE_CONTEXT_PATH)
public class CommonController {
    @Autowired
    private BasePaymentService paymentService;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @PostMapping(path = "/payment-details")
    public @ResponseBody
    PaymentDetail proceedPayment(@RequestBody PaymentDetail paymentDetail){
        if(paymentDetail.getGatewayId().equalsIgnoreCase("payu") ){
            paymentService.makePayment(paymentDetail);
        }
        else if(paymentDetail.getGatewayId().equalsIgnoreCase("rp")){
            paymentService.makePayment(paymentDetail);
        }
        return paymentDetail;
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*" )
    @RequestMapping(path = "/payment-response", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    Payment payuCallback(@RequestParam String mihpayid, @RequestParam String status, @RequestParam PaymentMode mode, @RequestParam String txnid, @RequestParam String hash, @RequestParam String amount, @RequestParam String productinfo, @RequestParam String firstname, @RequestParam String lastname, @RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String phone, @RequestParam String error, @RequestParam String bankcode, @RequestParam String PG_TYPE, @RequestParam String bank_ref_num, @RequestParam String unmappedstatus){
        log.info("inside callback");
        PaymentCallback paymentCallback = new PaymentCallback();
        paymentCallback.setMihpayid(mihpayid);
        paymentCallback.setTxnid(txnid);
        paymentCallback.setMode(mode);
        paymentCallback.setHash(hash);
        paymentCallback.setStatus(status);
        return paymentService.callbackPayment(paymentCallback);
    }
}
```